# How to Open Visual Studio 2012 Professional on Machine with Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

For testing, I need access to both Professional and Ultimate. I do not see how to open Professional after following these steps:
1. Ultimate previously installed
2. Professional was just installed with no errors
3. Visual Studio 2012 is in Windows 8 (by searching in Start screen) and selecting it brings up Ultimate
4. Professional not seen on the Start screen (just Visual Studio 2012 when searching)
5. Professional not seen in folders (missed it or ??)
I looked through stackoverflow posts as well as documentation but did not see the answer. How do I bring up Professional?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two different editions of *the same VS version* installed side-by-side.  This requirement is typically best handled by installing Professional into a VM.

You *can* have two different versions, ie: VS 2012 Ultimate and VS 2013 Professional, however.

Comment: I was afraid of that - thanks! It sure would be nice if the installation told us that (but maybe I missed it :)).